# Pretty print tree diagram from nested list string

Tags: php, data-structures, tree

I'm learning and stuck in solving this problem:

I want to create a tree, having a string with the following pattern:

```
1[2[3,5],4[7[6,9,11],8]]
```

Where 2 and 4 are children of 1; 3 and 5 are children of 2; 7 and 8 are children of 4; 6, 9, and 11 are children of 7; and so on.

And print a simple diagram of the tree structure, like this one:

```
            1
         /    \
        2      4
       / \    /  \
      3   5  7   8
           / | \
          6  9  11
```

Any help will be great.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's a good idea to give an attempt at this yourself and post an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of where you got stuck.

Comment: First you may need to build a token parser to convert your input into something usefull like an array or an object, then you'd need to construct the hierarchy to represent your tree. Unfortunetly your question is too broad.

Comment: Please elaborate your question by sharing your code or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Nice exercise. I'm putting this answer forth as not the best way but as a naive approach that can be improved upon.

First, the string needs to be parsed into a tree structure. Recursion is an obvious choice. There are many cleanup and error handling opportunities ahead, including using a stack to keep track of bracket pair indices.

Secondly, I believe the output you're looking for given a parsed tree structure is a tall order. What happens if a node has 60 children? Thinking about determining spacing for everything and doing height/width calculations led me to keep it simple and try something similar to `tree` that can be done in a few lines and handles a lot of edge cases automatically. Even here, adding padding for long root nodes could be a point of improvement.

```
function parse($data) {
    $result = [];
    $d = "";
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
        if (preg_match("/^[^\[\]\,]$/", $data[$i])) {
            $d = "";
            
            while ($i < count($data) && 
                   preg_match("/^[^\[\]\,]$/", $data[$i])) {
                $d .= $data[$i++];
            }
            
            $i--;
            $result[$d] = null;
        }
        else if (preg_match("/^[\[\]]$/", $data[$i])) {
            $closing_idx = -1;
            $level = 1;
            $j = $i + 1;
            
            for (; $j < count($data); $j++) {
                if ($data[$j] === "[") {
                    $level++;
                }
                else if ($data[$j] === "]") {
                    if (--$level === 0) {
                        $closing_idx = $j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            $cpy = [];
            
            for ($k = $i + 1; $k < $closing_idx; $k++) {
                $cpy[] = $data[$k];
            }
            
            $result[$d] = parse($cpy);
            $i = $closing_idx;
        }
    }
    
    return $result;
}

function print_tree($tree, $depth=0) {
    if ($tree) {
        foreach ($tree as $root => $child) {
            echo str_repeat(" ", $depth * 6);
            echo "$root " . ($child ? "────┐" : "") . "\n";
            print_tree($child, $depth + 1);
        }
    }
}
 
$data = "1[2[3,5],4[7[6,9,11],8]]";
print_tree(parse(str_split($data)));
```

Output:

```
1 ────┐
      2 ────┐
            3 
            5 
      4 ────┐
            7 ────┐
                  6 
                  9 
                  11 
            8
```